# Conditional styling in FME ChartGenerator

Tags: cartography, fme-form, chart

A vector data set represents different wilderness qualities of district areas (V, 1 and 2) and one human activity zone (N). Our cartography for the areas gives us the following map:

[image: Wilderness in Northern Norway]

I am using FME ChartGenerator to generate charts for all districts. FME produces excellent charts, with the exception of color scheme selection. I would like to control the pie level color conditional to the wilderness category so that the pies are visually linked to the cartography.

[image: Wilderness pie chart]

Is there a way to do this which does not involve post-processing color substitution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried setting/creating an 'fme_color' attribute and setting the 'color scheme' option to use it as highlighted below?

The following is taken from the offline ChartGenerator help files for FME and should get you on the right track:

"Color Scheme controls the color of the wedges based on a color ramp. If the Take from fme_color option is selected, color values for individual wedges can be supplied via the fme_color attribute. fme_color can be set by using the FeatureColorSetter transformer or by setting the value of this attribute to a valid RGB string e.g. (“1,0.5,0.3”)."

[image: ChartGeneratorDialog]